# I am getting the following exception after hosting in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, office-interop

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).**strong text**

upon clicking the button "Export to excel" which reads an excel file from a location, adds data into it and gets downloaded which is working fine in Localhost,but giving the above exception once hosted.

Please Refer to the code below

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

protected void Btn_EXcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                    

   xlexcel = new Excel.Application();//Exception is occuring in this line
  .
  .
  .              
}
```

Comment: Office installed on the server?

Comment: Yes,Office is installed on server,

Comment: I even followed the instructions of the video below,Despite I am getting the same error.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijfb3E_7t3o

Comment: Not sure, can you try Enable 32 bit Applications to True in Application Pool for the website?

Comment: Office applications should not be used server-side. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office